# How I can hide my wp folders from Inspect Element (Developer Tools)

Tags: plugins, security

When I open Inspect Element (Developer Tools) on my site, under **Source tab**, my WP folders are located such as `wp-admin`, `wp-content`, and `wp-include`. I want to hide all these folders for **security** reasons. Anyone tell me how to hide these manually or which plugin help me to hide these?

Comment: this have total zero to do with security.

Comment: You can't. If you see it, you already got it. By the way you didn't react to 2 of my previous answers about this subject, which will discourage users from answering your further question.

Comment: What do you mean by `hide`? You cannot really hide folders from yourself. Watching in developer tools means yourself. If you mean renaming them, then it's possible, but it'll not really give you additional security. Security through obscurity is a thing, but it only helps prevent automated attack targeted towards any default file or directory. However, if you have any security loop hole, then perhaps it's better to get hacked by automated tools than real people. Obscurity has its purpose, but calling it a security measure is rather a cliche.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress uses scripts and styles from these folders to function. You can not hide them, there is no security concerns with these folders, only public files can be accessed directly. Everything else can not. Dont waste your time here.

If you want to be secure add things like captcha, login limits, and strong passwords to prevent login attacks. Two factor auth is also a very strong measure. Wordpress itself is already very secure. You need to secure access.